# Plugin.Firebase Maui Errors: cannot convert argument on CrossFirebase.Initialize

Tags: firebase, maui

I am using Plugin.Firebase (v2.0.0) and i am using the below firebase recommended code in Maui.App.CreateBuilder and getting errors in Lambda expressions:

CS1503 Errors are:

> Argument 2: cannot convert from Android.OS.Bundle to Plugin.Firebase.Bundled.Shared.CrossFirebaseSettings

> Argument 1: cannot convert from UIKit.UIApplication to Plugin.Firebase.Bundled.Shared.CrossFirebaseSettings

> Argument 2: cannot convert from Foundation.NSDictionary to Firebase.Core.Options

Tried using casts, but that does work for these types.  Any suggestions?

```cs
using Plugin.Firebase.Auth;

#if IOS
using Plugin.Firebase.Bundled.Platforms.iOS;
#elif ANDROID
using Plugin.Firebase.Bundled.Platforms.Android;
#endif

public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .UseMauiCompatibility()
            .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
            .ConfigureSyncfusionCore()
            .RegisterFirebaseServices()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });
    
        return builder.Build();
    }

private static MauiAppBuilder RegisterFirebaseServices(this MauiAppBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events => {
#if IOS
            events.AddiOS(iOS => iOS.FinishedLaunching((app, launchOptions) => {
                CrossFirebase.Initialize(app, launchOptions);
                return false;
            }));
#else
            events.AddAndroid(android => android.OnCreate((activity,state) =>
                CrossFirebase.Initialize(activity,  state)));
#endif
        });

        builder.Services.AddSingleton(_ => CrossFirebaseAuth.Current);
        return builder;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post code or errors as images

Comment: @Jason thanks for the feedback, first post so not sure of etiquette.  I've updated.  thanks

Comment: Can you show the `using ...` part as well? Your problem most likely is that you didn't put any preprocessor directives around those.

Comment: @ewerspej I've updated to include the using.  thanks

Answer (score 4):

Seems like I had a similar problem and it was caused by my imports.

Previously, I had

```
#if IOS
    using Plugin.Firebase.Core.Platforms.iOS;
#else
    using Plugin.Firebase.Core.Platforms.Android;
#endif
```

Changed it to

```
using Plugin.Firebase.Bundled.Shared;

#if IOS
    using Plugin.Firebase.Bundled.Platforms.iOS;
#else
    using Plugin.Firebase.Bundled.Platforms.Android;
#endif
```

And now the `CrossFirebase.Initialize` accept the right arguments aka `CrossFirebaseSettings`

Like this

```
#if IOS
            events.AddiOS(iOS => iOS.FinishedLaunching((app, launchOptions) => {
                CrossFirebase.Initialize(CreateCrossFirebaseSettings());
                return false;
            }));
#else
            events.AddAndroid(android => android.OnCreate((activity, _) =>
                CrossFirebase.Initialize(activity, CreateCrossFirebaseSettings())));
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

The setup instructions in the documentation had a mistake, the `CrossFirebase.Initialize` method doesn't require any arguments on iOS and only an `Activity` on android, so your code should actually look like this:

```cs
#if IOS
            events.AddiOS(iOS => iOS.FinishedLaunching((app, launchOptions) => {
                CrossFirebase.Initialize();
                return false;
            }));
#else
            events.AddAndroid(android => android.OnCreate((activity, state) =>
                CrossFirebase.Initialize(activity)));
#endif
        });
```

The mistake in the readme got fixed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'll need to make sure that you're only targeting iOS and Android, because the Plugin doesn't support MacCatalyst and Windows, so you'll need to update the target frameworks in your project file **or** add conditional package includes:

```xml
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0-ios' OR '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0-android'">
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Firebase" Version="1.2.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Then, you'll need to make sure that you've also placed preprocessor directives around the `using ...` statements in the file where you also have the `RegisterFirebaseServices()` method:

```cs
#if IOS
using Plugin.Firebase.iOS;
#elif ANDROID
using Plugin.Firebase.Android;
#endif
```

Depending on the .NET version you're on, you may need to change the `net6.0-ios` and `net6.0-android` targets to `net7.0-ios` and `net7.0-android` *(or higher, for future readers)*.

That's all more or less described in the [documentation](https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase), as well.

Comment: I'm using package 2.0.0 , thee have been some changes since 1.2.0. I've followed the instruction in the documentation you referenced, and doesnt work.  The issue appears to be around injecting delegates and recognising the type of the parameters.