# Push notification on MAUI application using FCM

Tags: maui

I am trying to implement push notification on my `MAUI` application using `FCM`. I follow [this](https://cedricgabrang.medium.com/firebase-push-notifications-in-net-maui-android-32c808844d7e) blog and I did everything as per the blog.

They suggest to install only 2 NuGet packages, `Plugin.Firebase` and `Plugin.Firebase.Crashlytics`. (*I installed it by adding it on the .csproj like below*)

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net7.0-ios' OR '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net7.0-android'">
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Firebase" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Firebase.Crashlytics" Version="2.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

After adding the packages I have removed `Unsupported TargetFrameworks` by removing the MAC and windows framework code from .csproj file.

Then added the `google-services.json` file to the root folder of the project. But `GoogleServicesJson` Build Action is not showing in the list **(This is the very first problem I am facing)**. So I added it on the `.csproj` manually.

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net7.0-android'">
    <GoogleServicesJson Include="google-services.json" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Then updated `MauiProgram.cs` like below:

```
using Microsoft.Maui.LifecycleEvents;
using Plugin.Firebase.Auth;
using Plugin.Firebase.Bundled.Shared;
#if IOS
using Plugin.Firebase.Bundled.Platforms.iOS;
#else
using Plugin.Firebase.Bundled.Platforms.Android;
#endif

namespace MauiFirebaseDemo;

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .RegisterFirebaseServices()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

        return builder.Build();
    }

    private static MauiAppBuilder RegisterFirebaseServices(this MauiAppBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events => {
#if IOS
            events.AddiOS(iOS => iOS.FinishedLaunching((app, launchOptions) => {
                CrossFirebase.Initialize(CreateCrossFirebaseSettings());
                return false;
            }));
#else
            events.AddAndroid(android => android.OnCreate((activity, _) =>
                CrossFirebase.Initialize(activity, CreateCrossFirebaseSettings())));
#endif
        });

        builder.Services.AddSingleton(_ => CrossFirebaseAuth.Current);
        return builder;
    }

    private static CrossFirebaseSettings CreateCrossFirebaseSettings()
    {
        return new CrossFirebaseSettings(isAuthEnabled: true,);
    }
}
```

But a lot of properties in the new code are not exist. Check the below screenshots:

[image]

**Using section also has the same kind issues:** But the packages mention under using section are not installed.

[image]

**On android platform I have done the below set up.**

At `Platforms/Android/Resources/values` added the following line to `strings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <resources>
      <string name="com.google.firebase.crashlytics.mapping_file_id">none</string>
</resources>
```

Added the following ItemGroup to the.csproj file to prevent build errors:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net7.0-android'">
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib.Jdk7" Version="1.7.10" ExcludeAssets="build;buildTransitive" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib.Jdk8" Version="1.7.10" ExcludeAssets="build;buildTransitive" />
</ItemGroup>
```

In the `AndroidManifest.xml`. Added the following code snippet to the  tag :

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
    android:exported="false" />
    <receiver 
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then updated `MainActivity.cs` like below:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Plugin.Firebase.CloudMessaging;

namespace MauiFirebaseDemo;

[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        HandleIntent(Intent);
        CreateNotificationChannelIfNeeded();
    }

    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);
        HandleIntent(intent);
    }

    private static void HandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        FirebaseCloudMessagingImplementation.OnNewIntent(intent);
    }

    private void CreateNotificationChannelIfNeeded()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            CreateNotificationChannel();
        }
    }

    private void CreateNotificationChannel()
    {
        var channelId = $"{PackageName}.general";
        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        var channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "General", NotificationImportance.Default);
        notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        FirebaseCloudMessagingImplementation.ChannelId = channelId;
        //FirebaseCloudMessagingImplementation.SmallIconRef = Resource.Drawable.ic_push_small;
    }
}
```

Here also I am getting the same kind of error on code and using section:

[image]

Under using section:

[image]

Is this the right approach to implement push notification on `MAUI`? I saw a similar kind of implementation [here](https://www.andreasnesheim.no/push-notifications-in-net-maui-with-firebase/) too. How can I fix the error on `MauiProgram.cs` and `MainActivity.cs`? Should I install any other NuGet packages? How can I set GoogleServicesJson Build Action for google-services.json?

I have tried installing the `Plugin.Firebase.CloudMessaging` and `Plugin.Firebase.Auth` for resolving the errors on `MauiProgram.cs` and `MainActivity.cs`. And tried installing the `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement` for resolving the GoogleServicesJson Build Action, but no lucks.

All the errors are `does not exist in the current context`, that's why added screenshot in the question. Sample error details are added in text format below:

> The name 'CrossFirebase' does not exist in the current context

> The type or namespace name 'Firebase' does not exist in the namespace 'Plugin' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: You can check this article about [Plugin.Firebase Maui Errors: cannot convert argument on CrossFirebase.Initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75904143/plugin-firebase-maui-errors-cannot-convert-argument-on-crossfirebase-initialize). [.NET MAUI Push Notification for iOS](https://github.com/michalpr/Docs/blob/main/Firebase_MAUI_iOS_push_notification.md).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating the visual studio(Version 17.7.6) all these errors are gone and I am able to build the application and fetch the **FCM Token**.